# Проблема при установкe модуля pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x

Начал скачивать `pygame`, на сайт зайти не получилось, так как при заходе на него появлялась надпись:

> ☮  In solidarity with NZ Aotearoa we are offline today.

Когда скачивал по туториалам, вводил то, что вводили создатели туториалов

> (**pip install pygame или py -m pip install -U pygame --user**)

, но когда вводил в `cmd` или `terminal` в `pycharm`, то появлялась вот эта надпись:

> Collecting pygame
> Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... -(здесь был курсор)

а после писалась длииииинная ошибка:

> C:\Users\Тимофей>pip install pygame
> Collecting pygame
> Using cached pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz (10.1 MB)
> Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
>
> ```
>   × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
>   │ exit code: 1
>   ╰─> [61 lines of output]
>
>       WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
>       Using WINDOWS configuration...
>
>       Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
>         File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
>         File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\setup.py",
> ```
>
> line 359, in 
> buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\buildconfig\config.py",
> line 225, in main
> deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\buildconfig\config_win.py",
> line 497, in main
> and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py",
> line 290, in ask
> update(x86=x86, x64=x64)
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py",
> line 273, in update
> download_prebuilts(download_dir, x86=x86, x64=x64)
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py",
> line 124, in download_prebuilts
> download_sha1_unzip(url, checksum, temp_dir, 1)
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-m_ttsd5u\pygame_b8e669d10bca49dbb9f6810ecfffd94b\buildconfig\download_win_prebuilt.py",
> line 54, in download_sha1_unzip
> response = urllib.urlopen(request).read()
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 216, in urlopen
> return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 525, in open
> response = meth(req, response)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 634, in http_response
> response = self.parent.error(
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 563, in error
> return self._call_chain(*args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 496, in _call_chain
> result = func(*args)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^
> File "C:\Users\Тимофей\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\urllib\request.py",
> line 643, in http_error_default
> raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
> urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
> Making dir :prebuilt_downloads:
> Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip
> ed561079ec622b0bab5a9e02976f5d540b0622da
> Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2-devel-2.0.18-VC.zip:
> Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_image/release/SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip
> 137f86474691f4e12e76e07d58d5920c8d844d5b
> Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_image-devel-2.0.5-VC.zip:
> Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_ttf/release/SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip
> 1436df41ebc47ac36e02ec9bda5699e80ff9bd27
> Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_ttf-devel-2.0.15-VC.zip:
> Downloading... https://www.libsdl.org/projects/SDL_mixer/release/SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip
> 9097148f4529cf19f805ccd007618dec280f0ecc
> Unzipping :prebuilt_downloads\SDL2_mixer-devel-2.0.4-VC.zip:
> Downloading... https://www.pygame.org/ftp/jpegsr9d.zip ed10aa2b5a0fcfe74f8a6f7611aeb346b06a1f99
>
> ```
>       ---
>       For help with compilation see:
>           https://www.pygame.org/wiki/CompileWindows
>       To contribute to pygame development see:
>           https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>       ---
>
>       [end of output]
>
>   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
> error: metadata-generation-failed
>
> × Encountered error while generating package metadata.
> ╰─> See above for output.
>
> note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
> hint: See above for details.
> ```

Пробовал скачать по советам, которые помогают в моём случае, где скачиваешь библиотеку `pygame` через настройки. Но там у меня тоже появлялась ошибка. Если я скачивал pygame через `Python Packages`, то тоже была ошибка.
Что мне делать в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать `pip install -U pygame` в программе Anaconda Prompt(по  идеи, должна была установиться с питоном)

Comment: Такая программа не устанавливалась вместе с питоном. Ни с 3.11 ни с 3.7.9

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать

```
pip install pygame --pre
```

Comment: PS D:\Python\itProger_app> pip install pygame --pre
Collecting pygame
  Downloading pygame-2.1.3.dev8-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl (10.6 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.6/10.6 MB 1.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: pygame
Successfully installed pygame-2.1.3.dev8
_______________________________________
но **import pygame** не сработало

Comment: thanks "pip install pygame --pre" it worked
спасибо "pip install pygame --pre" сработало!!!